# Android - Custom List (Overlay elements that stay on certain positions in the list)

Tags: android, listview, custom-component, custom-lists, overlays

I want to create a custom-list in android like on this picture:

[image]

how should I create those custom elements in java-code?
I thought of creating a custom_element_layout.xml and then inflate it width a given height in java... is this possible?

and how can I make them overlaying the listelements and set their position? I haven't found a method in android's View.class that is called "setPosition(x,y)" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example that seems to explain what you are looking for [here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/08/overlay-on-android-listview.html). There should be a link to the source somewhere on the page.